# Digital input signal to be converted to analog signal

Tags: sensors

Hello and a very good day.
I am currently doing my final year project which involving Arduino KY-031 Knock Sensor as my input signal and it is apparently a digital type of sensor. So, my question is can the digital signal be converted to analog signal ?

The reason I need it to be analog signal because I wanted it to be classified into 3 type of stages (low,medium,high).
p/s: I am using Arduino Uno as my controller.

Comment: Yes, there is a [Digital-to-analog converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter). *it is apparently a digital type of sensor* - **what** is this sensor? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/).

Comment: The Arduino is a digital device. You are getting a digital input. How will it help to convert it to analog?

Comment: @NickGammon It's a KY-031 as per the question :-)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. If you want loudness then you need a different sensor, like a small microphone where you could detect the level of output from it.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an analogue representation of any signal - but you can't add in information which wasn't previously there.  The [KY-031](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-sensors-and-input/keyes-ky-031-arduino-knock-impact-sensor-manual-and-tutorial/) doesn't give you any more information than "knock" or "no knock", so there's no way to get further detail out of it.